# Php / Magento 'requires' Fatal Error .... need help interpreting problem

Tags: magento2, php, error, code

I am trying to install a new theme (not getting a reply from support about this and trying to fix it myself). After SFTP'ing the theme folders to my root folder, I am getting the following error when trying to load up the browser/GUI installer in Chrome/Safari.

Warning: require(/srv/public_html/pub/pearl-theme-installation/../app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/public_html/pub/pearl-theme-installation/index.php on line 6

Warning: require(/srv/public_html/pub/pearl-theme-installation/../app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/public_html/pub/pearl-theme-installation/index.php on line 6

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/srv/public_html/pub/pearl-theme-installation/../app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /srv/public_html/pub/pearl-theme-installation/index.php on line 6

My limited knowledge and understanding tells me that the index.php file requires but cannot find the bootstrap.php file? Is this correct? And if so would it be likely that I have put the theme folders in the wrong place? I have tried to research how to read errors and interpret them, but I am a bit stuck. Thanks.

Comment: share more details like current folder structure

Comment: where you have copied your theme let me know the path

Comment: There were 3 folders as part of the theme files: I put the pearl-theme-installation folder in srv/public_html/pub/pearl-theme-installation

Comment: Then there was an APP and a PUB folder in the theme package which I moved the contents of to the srv/public_html/app/ and srv/public_html/pub folders.

Answer (score 0):

As per the details you shared i think you must set proper filer/folder permissions.

> The owner of the Magento file system: Must have full control (read/write/execute) of all files and directories.

To know about the same , you can visit [set permission](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;  
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

It also depends how you installed the `Magento` .
If installed by composer than run `composer install` first

Comment: there is `config.php` file in this theme, where you have to set correct path